# Advice for move partitions from secondary OS to primary

Tags: partitioning, gpt

I'm faced with the following scenario:

I have a Thinkpad X1 Yoga laptop that came with Windows 10. I have since shrinked the NTFS partition to dual boot an Arch Linux installation, and have been using it for over a year. I am now considering removing Win10 entirely since I don't really need it, and either dedicate the entire disk to Arch or have it half-and-half with another distribution.

[This is what the current GPT partitioning table looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7W4F.png) The partitions are:

- sda1: EFI boot
- sda2: Miscosoft reserved partition
- sda3: Windows 10
- sda4: Windows 10 recovery
- sda5: Arch root partition
- sda6: Arch swap
- sda7: Arch /home

What's the best way to go about this? It seems to me these are the options I have:

1. Deleting partitions 2-4 and moving the Arch partitions left while expanding them as necessary. Is this a safe way to go about this? Is it easy to then repair GRUB so it knows where the new location of the partition is?
2. Backing up the Arch partitions and simply formatting the entire drive, then restoring them. I would of course not prefer this and would only do it if option #1 is not viable for some reason. I would also need a method to easily image just the `/` and `/home` partitions to recover them easily.

Does option #1 carry any risks or difficulties that I am not aware of? Is there anything else I should know about and read up on before attempting it? Any general advice on the process? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does option #1 carry any risks or difficulties that I am not aware of?

None that I can think of; it's a straightforward move. But make your root partition large enough so that you won't need to shrink /home later.

(Currently as the partitions are small, the move should be fast and mostly non-overlapping. However, shrinking /home *and* moving it to the right, this time overlapping the old location, will be two risky operations in addition to taking a lot of time.)

Don't forget to delete "Windows Boot Manager" from your firmware boot menu (using `efibootmgr`), and the related bootloader files from the EFI system partition.

> Is it easy to then repair GRUB so it knows where the new location of the partition is?

At most you should need to run `grub-install...` and `grub-mkconfig...` to rebuild everything.

(The GRUB core image understands the partition tables so it doesn't care about the *location,* exactly, but it might care about the partition *number*. It seems that depending on the system, grub-install will reference the /boot partition either by its UUID or by its numerical index.)

Comment: I know how to use efibootmgr, but when you're talking about deleting the bootloader files from the EFI system partition, does this just involve mounting /efi/boot and removing the windows (or microsoft? I forget the name) directory?

Comment: Yes, everything under `EFI\Microsoft` and probably also the `EFI\Boot\Bootx64.efi` file. (That's probably a copy of Windows' bootmgfw.efi.)